# How to use user capability as variable in a build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use a self-hosted agent. Its system capabilities are visible in the agents pool view.

I added some capabilities as user capabilities  like :

[image: user capacities]

Is there a way to access this user capabilities  as a variable in the build : something like $(CodeSigning)?

Comment: The word you are looking for is **capability**, not capacity. Capacity has a very different meaning.

Comment: @DanielMann, thanks. I translated from french to capacity instead of capability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use one extension [Agent Capabilities](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernfrost.agent-capabilities&ssr=false#overview) to achieve accessing agent capability via variable.

Step:

1) Install it into your organization, then add one task `Agent Capabilities` into pipeline. After this task executed finished, all of Capabilities will be transferred as variables, both system and user capability.

[image]

2) Generate PAT and set it as secret variable. Name it as `AgentCapabilitiesAccessToken`.

[image]

3) Now, you can access **system capability** with format `$(AgentCapabilities.System.xxxx)`.

For **user capability** via `$(AgentCapabilities.User.xxxx)`. For example: `$(AgentCapabilities.User.CodeSigning)`

[image]

Comment: This is what i needed but the extension is not available on premise!

Comment: I used [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cory-r-stein.AgentCapabilitiesToVars) instead

Answer (score 1):

Capabilities are meant to check if an agent has a certain capability. Meaning: if your build has a certain need that can be matched by a build agent you can do so by using capabilities. **Capabilities are not environment parameters.** Don't believe me? Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool-demands?view=azure-pipelines#remarks).

For example: This build agent is located in the T environment (test).

[image]

My build pipeline runs certain tests that need "test environment" endpoints. You can define in your yaml pipeline that you need an agent located in T by using the capabilities.

```
pool:
  name: MyDefaultAgentPool
  demands:
     - Environment -equals T
```

Comment: This answer certainly helped me! Thank you!